# Theme isnt changing using Gnome Tweak Tool

Tags: gnome, themes, 12.10, window

In 12.04 I used Unity and was able to change the theme with the gnome-tweak-tool.

Since the update to 12.10 I use gnome and try to change the theme however nothing changes except the top bar which I changed in a different way.

I applied the theme with the tweak tool and I logged out and in again, I even tried it with restarting the PC and that didnt work either.
I hope You can help me.

screenshot:

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/2v96xph.jpg]

Sorry dont know how to put the picture inside -.-

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the default Ubuntu "Gnome" related applications and tools.  Ubuntu picks the gnome applications that work best with Unity.

I use the Gnome 3 PPA (https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) which has the latest and greatest, but this will also make changes to other programs like Nautilus which I personally like, but others might not.  Not an exact answer, but if you like running a Gnome desktop like I do.  It might be nice although I've personally noticed a lot of the gnome shell extensions aren't working with 3.6 yet.

Hope this helps.